# dual monitor or 2 windows output windows executable

Tags: godot

I have a touch screen AND a 4K screen.

The touch screen would have user input and the secondary screen will display the result.

How DO I configure Godot to open 2 windows or an executable to open up on both monitors.

My fall back would be forcing the output executable to encompass 2 monitors and have 2 viewports and 2 cameras.

Comment: According to this: https://ask.godotengine.org/77385/is-it-possible-to-have-one-game-on-multiple-monitors seems that if both screens have the same resolution, you can set the windows size to the total resolution of both screens. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes that works thanks. Only if both monitors share same resolution.